# How is my new PC making webcam video grainy?

Tags: windows, usb, hardware-failure, windows-11, webcam

I recently built a new PC. It is running Windows 11. I had everything working great, including the webcam.  Last night I swapped my HDMI cables for DP cables.  No problems. But then I checked my webcam and it looked super grainy. Just absolutely the worst quality I've seen in a webcam in 10+ years. (It's a ~$100 webcam.)  I have no idea why it's suddenly doing this.  Some troubleshooting I've tried:

- Switching back to HDMI cables (no effect)
- Trying a different high quality webcam (no effect, same issue on that cam)
- Plugging the camera in to different USB ports (no effect)
- Unplugging all other USB devices except for the camera (no effect)
- Trying my webcam on a different computer (looks perfect)
- Tried changing resolutions (no effect)

So it just seems that any webcam on this computer will suddenly look bad. How is that possible?

Here is some video of what it looks like. Something about the youtube encoding is making it look not nearly as bad as it is, but if you look at my guitar on the wall, you'll get some idea of what the problem looks like, but it's much worse than that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB0B7YL-qlI

This is on Windows 11.  Webcams tried are:

- Logitech Brio 4K Webcam, Ultra 4K HD Video Calling, Noise-Canceling mic, HD Auto Light Correction, Wide Field of View, Works with Microsoft Teams, Zoom, Google Voice, PC/Mac/Laptop/Macbook/Tablet
- Logitech for Creators StreamCam Premium Webcam for Streaming and Content Creation, Full HD 1080p 60 fps, Premium Glass Lens, Smart Auto-Focus, for PC/Mac – Graphite
- Anker PowerConf C200 2K

Comment: I wonder if some setting got changed. What're you using to record/get the footage? Any other changes?

Comment: The Windows Camera app, Microsoft Teams, and Clipchamp.  Doesn't seem to be application specific.

Comment: I'm making a wild ass guess but I wonder if the resultion the camera is recording at changed, and the down/up sampling is potato grade .

Comment: Tried various resolutions with no change in result.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add details on the exact make and model of the webcam?

Comment: It's multiple webcams, but I added them

Comment: Did you use Logitech G Hub to mess with any settings? This will store and push presets to Logitech cameras and so they don't get reset to defaults when unplugging.

Comment: No.  I haven't tried Logitech software.  But maybe I should.  Maybe it could give me some more insight in to what is going on.

Comment: The Logitec software can't even recognize that logitec webcams are connected (but they show in the device tree, and I can view them in the camera app).  I also have tried a 3rd camera now, not logitec, and it looks as bad or worse as the others.